# Why does rpm --whatrequires fail to report dependencies?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm, openssl

I am considering using [LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL for CentOS 7](http://librelamp.com). Since this machine will be very limited in what services it runs, I wondered whether OpenSSL could be removed entirely.

```
#> rpm -qa | grep ssl
openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
```

Okay, so try

```
#> rpm -q --whatrequires openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
no package requires openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
#> rpm -q --whatrequires openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
no package requires openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
```

Really?

```
#> sudo yum remove openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64
```

This gives lots of lines such as this:

```
--> Processing Dependency: perl(IPC::Cmd) >= 0.42 for package: perl-File-Fetch-0.42-2.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-File-Fetch.noarch 0:0.42-2.el7 will be erased
```

etc ad nauseum, then

```
Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

I wasn't expecting removing OpenSSL to happen without complaint, but why does `rpm -q --whatrequires` fail to report these depenencies?

**How do I list all packages which require, directly or indirectly, a given package?**

By this I mean: if package X were to be removed, and package/file Y will be removed if X is removed, and package Z depends on Y, how do I list all such Z for any given X?

Comment: I wonder if you ever tried `rpm -q --whatrequires openssl`, i.e. specifying a "capability" instead of a package name that includes a version number. `rpm -q --whatrequires` is intended to be used with a capabillty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned other packages may require files or something else from the "provides" list of the package:

```
rpm -q --list openssl openssl-libs
rpm -q --provides openssl openssl-libs
```

To see whether there are *some* "whatrequires" (not all):

```
rpm -e --test openssl openssl-libs
```

To list *all* is IMO not directly possible with `rpm` but in `yum` case (untested):

```
yes "N" | yum remove openssl openssl-libs
```

or

```
yum deplist openssl openssl-libs
```

or

```
repoquery --alldeps --whatrequires openssl openssl-libs
```

Answer (score 1):

that just means nobody explicitly asks for that package to be installed; but some packages can depend on files installed by those packages. For example on my machine; nobody depends on the package; but some depend on the library provided by the package:

```
$ rpm -q libopenssl1_0_0-32bit
libopenssl1_0_0-32bit-1.0.1i-18.1.x86_64 # whence this package is installed
$ rpm -q --whatrequires libopenssl1_0_0-32bit
no package requires libopenssl1_0_0-32bit
$ rpm -ql libopenssl1_0_0-32bit
/lib/engines
/lib/engines/libcapi.so
/lib/engines/libgmp.so
/lib/engines/libgost.so
/lib/engines/libpadlock.so
/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
$ rpm -q --whatrequires libssl.so.1.0.0
libldap-2_4-2-32bit-2.4.41-14.1.x86_64
cups-libs-32bit-1.7.5-7.1.x86_64
```

**EDIT** due to edited question:

you can use `rpm -e --test` to find out which are those rpms. With some bash processing you can get a clean list:

```
$ rpm -e --test libopenssl1_0_0-32bit 2>&1 | grep needed | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq
cups-libs-32bit-1.7.5-7.1.x86_64
libldap-2_4-2-32bit-2.4.41-14.1.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks. So how do I list dependencies of all files contained in a package? Question edited.

Comment: edited my answer